# How to get an object by id in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to get a particular object from Django... When I use filter it returns more than one and I need just one and I don't want to my fields unique... Is there a way I can get object by id since id will be the only unique field by default in Django Sqlite

Comment: filtering with id wont give you multiple Records. Check the code you might have missed something. Id is unique field. and if you're not using ID for filter. you can use like this for one record.
.first()

Comment: Filtering might only give you one, but a filter will return a queryset, not a single instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose one of these methods to get the object related to `id` you entered:

##### `get_object_or_404()` function:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

model_object = get_object_or_404(ModelName, id=id)
```

##### `.get_or_create()` method:

```py
model_object, created = ModelName.objects.get_or_create(id=id)
```

##### `.filter()` and `.first()` methods:

```py
model_object = ModelName.objects.filter(id=id).first()
```

Comment: This returns Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>

Comment: @abigaildaniel The answer is only an example, we are not magicians, would you please share your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two methods [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get) or more better   [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) as it *calls get() on a given model manager, but it raises [Http404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/views/#django.http.Http404) instead of the model’s [DoesNotExist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/class/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist) exception*.

Implementation of `get()`:

```py
SomeModelName.objects.get(id=id)
```

Implementation of `get_object_or_404()`:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

get_object_or_404(SomeModelName,id=id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Yourtablename.objects.get(pk=id)
```

Or use filter.